# Some of users lose session info in my website (PHP). How can i prevent this?

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

In my website, some of users complain about problems in logging in.

Their browsers generally don't see session info and cannot understand that the user is logged in, and behave like never logged in. But after some refresh, browser see session info and show the user as logged in normally. Again, if the user try to do some action( like writing a message) browser again loose the session info and redirect to the login page. The situation continues like that.

Browser security options, cookie options of the user's computer are all the same as mine.

I never face such a problem but they do.

How can i solve the problem, actually how can i see,understand the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but what about timeouts?

Comment: Without code, there is no way for us but to guess. You probably will have to do some debugging on an affected system. Maybe your session system is sensitive of IP changes on the client side?

Comment: timouts are long enough, and most of users doesn't see any problem. just some users...

Comment: Pekka, the user is in other city, i try to do debugging on the phone but it is nearly impossible :)

what debugging technique you offer? And how can i follow the client's IP change?

Comment: @teofte you could consider using a remote control tool like VNC to log in on their desktop, or trying to replicate the user's environment as closely as possible - OS, browser, type of internet connection... Re IP change, you would have to look into your code to see whether sessions break if the IP changes.

Comment: @Pekka thanks, but i wonder something, let's say IP is changing, and session is lost because of this. But after some refresh, session is again shown. Is it possible in such a situation?

Comment: @teofte impossible to judge without knowing the code you are using to do the login with. Sadly, I know of no easy facility to simulate changing IPs... Maybe worth a separate question on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be unable to reproduce the problem, and getting to their machine may not be an option, you could potentially have them run something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (ie), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (firefox), etc, then send you the logs.

As gavtaylor suggested, I'd be suspicious of a load balancer, proxy, or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for correcting that AlexV.  It wouldn't let me add both links in (properly) as it gave me some error about the possibility of spam (I suppose due to the fact that I'm just getting started here - offering some answers).  /shrug

Answer (score 1):

The usual recipe is:

- try to reproduce the problem
- if this fails add more logging
- if still not clear, then debug the code

Assuming the first one has failed, then you might want to start [logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html) the value of the [session cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

Superficially, this sounds like a caching issue.

Answer (score -1):

is your server load balanced?
I had this problem recently were users of one of our old sites were temporarily "losing" their logged in state.

We found that the loadbalancer wasn't implementing sticky sessions properly so people were jumping between servers and because the site was using server sessions, instead of database sessions, people were effectively logged out on one server but logged in on the other...

Comment: Sticky sessions suck - they totally undermine the HA reasons for using a load balancer